# Discord.js - Adding queue function to music system

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Yes, I know there are a lot of threads on here regarding this topic. HOWEVER; I've found that in most cases, it is kind of dependant on what your music code looks like. Therefore, I decided to not mess too much around and potentially break my code and clutter it with stuff I won't need.

So here I go.

Below is the code I have in my play.js file. Most of it I got through a guide I found just to get me going then I tweaked it a bit to be more suitable for my use.

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');

    //Setting up constants
    const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
    const ytSearch = require("yt-search");
    const voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;


    // Check if user is in voiceChannel
    if (!voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send(errorVoiceEmbed);

    // Check if we have the correct permissions
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(msg.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has("CONNECT")) return msg.channel.send(permsEmbed);
    if (!permissions.has("SPEAK")) return msg.channel.send(permsEmbed);

    // Check if a second argument has been passed
    if (!args.length) return msg.channel.send(playEmbed);

    // Validating the passed URL
    const validURL = (str) => {
      var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
      if (!regex.test(str)){
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }

      // If we have a valid URL, load it and play the audio
      if(validURL (args[0])){
        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        const stream = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});

        connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})

        // Leave when done
        .on('finish', () => {
          voiceChannel.leave();
          msg.channel.send(completedEmbed);
        });
        await msg.reply(playingEmbed);

        return
      }

      const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

      // If a user enters a search query instead of a link, Search YouTube and play a result.
      const videoFinder = async (query) => {
        const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

        return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
      }

      const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

      if (video) {
        const stream = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});

        connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
        .on('finish', () => {
          voiceChannel.leave();
          msg.channel.send(completedEmbed);
        });

        await msg.reply (playingEmbed);
      } else {
        msg.channel.send(noResultsEmbed);
      }
```

So - How would I go about adding a proper queue to this? I'm looking for a separate queue command that ties in perfectly with the play command. Therefore - I'm gonna be using two different files that would need to communicate through a songlist of some sort. How this would be done tho, I'm unsure. I looked into just using arrays for this but didn't manage to get that working.

And before you ask - Those embeds that are used in those msg.channel.send statements are embeds configured earlier up in the file. I didn't include these in here but they're there.

**PLEASE NOTE:**
I'm not looking for a complete solution. I just want some tips and hints as to how I can solve this in a simple and effective way without having to clutter up the code I already have.

That being said - Just on it's own, the code for the play command works perfectly . It plays either the requested song from the link provided or a song from the search query. But when a new song is requested, the old one just stops and the new one plays. You all know how this should go. If no song is playing, play it. If a song is played, add the requested song to the queue and play that once the previous song is done etc etc.

Comment: You should implement a queue, using an array for example. Then you can check if the array is empty (start playing immediately) otherwise, add to the end of the array and work your way through it using the `finish` event to remove the first element.

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti that's a good idea. Never thought about using that finish event.